# How to create a function to direct create a file based on current word under the point and open it?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I know Org-mode has a key combo `[C-c C-o]` for opening a link.
I want to *append* a function into this key combo. This function will detect whether has a link under the point, if not, then create a file which based on the word under the point or selected string and auto open it. This file has a filename with the word or the selected string. like `org-mode.org`.

I wish this appended function will not affect original key combo function.

--- update ---

I think Emacs Lisp function `defadvice` might is for this. But I know Emacs Lisp a little.
Is it simple to append ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't imagine this kind of thing being very useful as to create a file
you need a directory. The only one that's reasonable is the current directory.
So this function will create it there if it doesn't exist.

There's little hope of chaining it to `org-open-at-point` since it's huge and doesn't
return a fail code.

```lisp
(defun find-file-at-point-ex ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename
         (expand-file-name
          (thing-at-point 'filename))))
    (when (or
           (file-exists-p filename)
           (y-or-n-p (format "Create %s?" filename)))
      (find-file filename))))
```

Comment: How? The function doesn't return anything, doesn't throw and changes its behavior depending on what features are loaded?

Comment: Make a defadvice "around"?  Before: make some check with what's Under point. Depending on that, call the orginal org-open-at-point, of make your own stuff?

Comment: Have a look at the source of `org-open-at-point`. It's 200 lines of checking what's at point.
What you suggest is just re-implementing that.